# Odd Exception Scenario System.Net.Http MediaTypeHeaderValue cannot be cast to MediaTypeHeaderValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I've just started getting this odd Exception being thrown and I'm completely unsure how to move forward and solve it.

`[A]System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue cannot be cast to [B]System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.`

`Type A originates from 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'.`

`Type B originates from 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'`

The error occurs in my WebAPI on the client side on this line:

`var data = responsecontent.ReadAsAsync<List<MyClass>>().Result;`

I've checked every single reference to this DLL both in my web site which hosts the API client and in the API solution.  They are all referencing the exact same dll:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll`

I have noticed that the API is using a newer version of the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` dll but its only  minor version increment and it was updated as a dependency to something else so I'm loathed to try and "downgrade" and create another issue in the process.

API System.Net.Http.Formatting is:

`\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.1.0-alpha-121112\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`

Web Site System.Net.Http.Formatting is:

`\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`

I do find it concerning that NuGet will download alpha packages as dependencies even with "Stable Only" selected in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that something had gone very wrong with some NuGet updates and it had created a rogue binding redirects in my web.config file on the client side.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Changing this back to the previous version:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Fixed everything on the client side.

Comment: I appreciate you coming back to answer this.

Comment: I had the same issue but get this when trying your solution: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0` Any ideas?

Comment: Check the redirecting for that dll. Could be that it's required and not there or set up wrong.